# less.css - how to style / escape square brackets

Tags: css, escaping, less

I have a web app (which I did not create) that includes the following element:

```
<label for="photo[]"></label>
```

Yes, I am aware this is suboptimal but the person that created the app can't be convinced any alternative is possible. I was wondering if it was possible to style this element in less.css without refactoring the code?

Muy first instinct was:

```
label[for=photo\\[\\]]
```

but this doesn't work. I've also tried:

```
label[for=photo\[\]]
```

and

```
label[for=photo\\\[\\\]]
```

How can I select this element, by its label, for styling in less?

[A JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/385nJ/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be missing the point, but have you tried quoting the attribute selector?

**Less**

```
label[for="photo[]"] {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
}
```

Seems to be applying the styles properly ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RqZSa/)).

On a side note, [Codepen](http://codepen.io/) is a great alternative to JSfiddle with less/sass (and even HAML/Markdown) support. I've made an example codepen here:

http://codepen.io/NickTomlin/pen/gakci

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Unicode escape:

```
label[for=photo\5B \5D ]
```